# Libgdx internal sqlite database access

Tags: java, sqlite, libgdx

I am currently writing a game using libgdx, I have setup a sqlite DB with all the information required for the game and I am using the [SQLite JDBC Driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) to connect to my database, this works great, however when I compile it to a jar file using `./gradlew desktop:dist` it cannot access the database from the assets folder.

The command I am using to connect to the database is:

```
Connection sqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + databaseName)
```

From my understanding of this it's because it's not pointing to the database using Gdx's file handler.

Is there a simple solution to this rather than having to ship both the DB and jar file separate?

Answer (score 0):

See [from](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling)

> Internal files are relative to the application’s root or working directory on desktops, relative to the assets directory on Android, and relative to the core/assets/ directory of your GWT project. These files are read-only

You could use something like this to access the internal files asset folder.

```
FileHandle fileHandle = Gdx.files.internal(path);
```

> Is there a simple solution to this rather than having to ship both the DB and jar file separate?

The JSON from Libgdx can work well for reading/writing and for storing information and can be used for different platforms. See this for more info:[wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON)